# Selenium web driver fails to click to foreground dialog's OK button and finds background dialog's OK button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium web driver 3.0 and want to click to OK button from active dialog from opened two dialogs (one is in background and second is in foreground). How can I click to foreground dialog OK button from parent div from below html? I tried using nth-child and nth-of-type but click always finds first dialog showing in background and web driver fails to click to OK button.

When I check we.isDisplayed() then it finds first OK button too, I want method for we.isDisplayed() for 2nd dialog OK button.

## Html

```
<div id="z_shell" class="DwtShell">

    <div id="Dialog1" class="DwtDialog">
       <td id="ErrorDialog_button1_title" class="ZWidgetTitle">OK</td>
       <td id="ErrorDialog_button2_title" class="ZWidgetTitle">Cancel</td>
    </div>

    <div id="Dialog2" class="DwtDialog">
       <td id="ErrorDialog_button2_title" class="ZWidgetTitle">OK</td>
    </div>

</div>
```

Note: Dialog div id can be anything, but class name is fixed: DwtDialog.

Tried code:

```
WebDriver webDriver;
WebElement we = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='DwtDialog']:nth-child(2) td[id$='_button2_title']:contains('OK')"));
visible = we.click();
// Click fails here
```

Tried locators:

```
By.cssSelector("div[class='DwtDialog']:nth-child(2) td[id$='_button2_title']:contains('OK')")

By.xpath("//div[@class='DwtDialog'][2]//td[@id='ErrorDialog_button2_title' and contains(text(), 'OK')]")

By.xpath("//div[@id='z_shell']//div[@class='DwtDialog'][2]//td[@id='ErrorDialog_button2_title' and contains(text(), 'OK')]")
```

### Problem

How can I click to OK button of dialog which is visible? Mostly this dialog is loaded later. I meant `nth-child(2)` and for 3rd dialog `nth-child(3)` as a hint.

Comment: Can you try a different strategy - relying on the dialog's title or information message? (this part of the HTML is not expanded on the screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for comment, any dynamic dialog can come. Only class name is fixed and one must be active, rest would be in background.

Comment: Use an id from inside, like the one of the tr and/or an id from a div that is inside.

Comment: OK id is same inside div, one is active and 2nd is inactive as a difference.

Comment: That should be enough, use css like: div#divId[style*='block'] and add the button identifier.For a complete css selector i need the html snippet, copy/paste it in the question with in a <code> </code> block, you can delete/change any private info.

Comment: Sorry and thanks Lauda. It doesn't work, because both having display block and sub dialog comes over parent dialog when passing wrong data. Updated full html, you can take a look now.

Comment: I took a look, too much html, it is a little hard without seeing the page, I will try more.What you need to do is to find an unique attribute in any parent that you can use, for example if these are the main divs you could use role like div[role='role=dialog'] and continue from there.

Comment: I found a solution! Wait posting it, interesting!

Comment: You posted a massive amount of HTML but not the relevant part. You didn't include the error message portion or either of the id="ErrorDialog" portions. Please post only the relevant parts so we can help.

Comment: is ok, very good it has the solution

Comment: @JiteshSojitra if you want to post more HTML, just do it on pastebin.com or something like that... and post relevant HTML. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I missed the comment about the id's changing... try #2. I think something like this should work but I can't test it without the page. Basically we grab all the buttons `td.ZWidgetTitle` on dialogs `div.DwtDialog`. If it is visible and contains "OK", click it.

```
List<WebElement> dialogButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.DwtDialog > td.ZWidgetTitle"));
for (WebElement dialogButton : dialogButtons)
{
    if (dialogButton.isDisplayed() && dialogButton.getText().equals("OK"))
    {
        dialogButton.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

After getting more info, here's another approach. It's hard to figure out if this stuff will work without access to the site but this will hopefully point you in the right direction if it doesn't work. This will get all the OK buttons on error dialogs. The problem is, which one is clickable? We can eat the exception that is thrown when another element would receive the click until we find one that doesn't throw... that's the right one. I did some local testing and this code seems to work for me.

```
List<WebElement> dialogButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[starts-with(@id, 'ErrorDialog_button') and text()='OK']"));
System.out.println(dialogButtons.size());
System.out.println(dialogButtons.size());
for (WebElement dialogButton : dialogButtons)
{
    try
    {
        dialogButton.click();
    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that div id changes as described in the Note from the question and if class will be used there is a chance that while throw an error if needed to click on the first button of the second div as position in the page.

Comment: @lauda Yeah I missed that note at first... I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, your answer is definitely helpful but it gives me 0 elements. I think css needs to be fixed. I tried div.DwtDialog > td#ErrorDialog_button2_title but that doesn't work too. Is there anything we are missing?

Comment: Is the HTML you posted exactly the same as the original page? Can you link the page or post the HTML on pastebin.com or something?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, i did the same and understandable tweak needs to be done as you will not have site access. Looks good!